# Create template files from output.tf - Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-aws

I want to create folders/files from the combination of template files & vars from a main.tf in an output.tf.

I saw a module that seems perfect for my objective but I need to apply specific names for my files.

```
resource "template_dir" "config" {
  source_dir      = "..."
  destination_dir = "..."

  vars = {
    example_name = var.example_name
  }
}
```

Right now I using the next combination of two modules:

```
data "template_file" "example_template" {
  template = file("${path.module}/templates/proyect-name/one/something.yml")
  vars = {
    example_name = var.example_name
  }
}

resource "local_file" "example_file" {
  content = data.template_file.example_template.rendered
  filename = "${var.outputs_final_path}/${var.example_name}/${var.example_name}_something.yml"
}
```

But I end up having 600+ lines of code....is there a "cleaner" way to create it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your use-case completely, but a combination of
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/templatefile.html
and  
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/local/latest/docs/resources/file
should do the trick. 
Adding a `count` to your resource depending on your vars will produce n(`count`) files

Comment: Hi, yes works but defining a tree structure of folder/files with two modules cost 600+ lines of code. template_dir do it flawlessly in a unique module but don't let me specify the name of some files (depends on project name var). I also try creating with templete_dir and local_file to try a kind of rename file but doesn't work...
If templete_dir knew how to interpret variables in the filenames used as templates...

Comment: Something like https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/looking-for-a-way-to-render-template-directories-including-templated-directory-names/19843 but without using  hashicorp/dir/template